# Popover color on iPad

Tags: ipad

I want to show the Popover in its default style (Default Blue). My Top tool bar style is Black translucent, So I need to change the Barstyle of the Rootviewcontroller to black translucent in landscape mode. How can i show the same controller in two modes with two diff styles ?

ie, Want to have to default style at Portrait mode, and Black translucent at Landscape mode.

Tried to change in ViewWillAppear,
But cant change it back to default style, as UIBarStyleDefault sets light gray color and not the default blue.

Thanks for your time.!

Gopi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer.
adding a line in split view delegate method, solve this prob.

```
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

    [(UINavigationController *)aViewController navigationBar].barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

}
```

Cheers!!